Qualtrics - Carrying forward randomized order of subset of mc response options to next question, while preserving exclusive anchored options
I would like to do the following with multiple choice, select all, questions Q10 and Q11 (screenshot below):
Question Q10 and Q11
Step 1. Randomize the order of the 1st 7 response options (the brands) while anchoring the last 2 response options both of which must be “exclusive” response options (i.e., when either 8 or 9, the last options, is selected, no other choices can be selected). This Step can be done using advanced randomization for Q10.
However, basic functionality in Qualtrics won't accomplish Step 2, below.
Step 2. I want to present the same randomized order of the 1st 7 response options (the brands) from Q10 to Q11 (i.e., the randomized order of brands in Q11 must appear in the same randomized order as they appeared in Q10) while, at the same time, anchoring the last 2 response options, both of which must still be “exclusive” response options.
Step 2 cannot be done using “carry forward choices” because the “advanced randomization” from Q10 cannot be carried over to Q11 while ensuring that options 8 and 9, the last options, are exclusive options. In other words, when using Qualtrics standard features, using “carry forward choices” presents options 8 and 9 as non-exclusive response options in Q11 (I don't know why it can't preserve the exclusive options).
Question 1: How can I accomplish Step 2? What is the simplest way, JS or Survey Flow? If JS, what code would be required? (I’m novice at JS)
Question 2: Additionally, how can I record the order that response options were presented in Q10 and Q11 in the output of the dataset? (Ideally it would be a single variable and data would appear as, e.g., “1,4,5,2,3,7,6,8,9”)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
